# Check if number start with 0 or 00

Tags: php, regex

I would like to know how to check with regex or whatever if a number begins with 0 or 00
I did so but I'm newbie at regex:

```
preg_match("/^[0][0-9]+$/", $number)
```

Comment: Can access the string as an array and check the first character: `($number[0]==="0")` (if it's not necessary to verify the whole string being composed of digits)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
^(?:0|00)\d+$
```

Try this.See demo,

http://regex101.com/r/rQ6mK9/16

Answer (score 7):

You may try the below code

```
if (preg_match("~^0\d+$~", $number)) {
     // Yes
}
else {
     // no
}
```

**Explanation:**

```
^                        the beginning of the string
0                        '0' 
\d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times)
$                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                         string
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/rQ6mK9/18)

Comment: `^0\d+$` seems equivalent. You don't need `{1, 2}` quantifier

Comment: that's even better... :-)

Comment: It is not equivalent I think cause it could result in numbers like these: 01XXXXXXXX 02XXXXXXXX ....

Answer (score 4):

This problem doesn't really require regex. Just use [substr function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php):

```
if (substr($str, 0, 1) == '0' || substr($str, 0, 2) == '00') {
    //=> matched
}
```

Comment: $quantity = 05;
echo substr($quantity, 0, 1); //output is 5